# BBpress integrate with my custom theme

Tags: wordpress, bbpress

everywhere, i mean everyone on every tutorial is mentioned, that you must install the plugin like this

1) Visit the WordPress Administration Screen and navigate to Plugins > Add New.

2) Search for bbPress

3) Locate the bbPress plugin and click install

4) Activate the plugin

But i dont want people to have to install it, **i want the plugin to be allready integrated in my custom theme** im building. But when i copied it to my plugin folder (in my custom theme folder, not the “wp-conetnt/plugins” !!), and i required it in my functions.php. after this, the web get stacked, it kills my browser, because there is hundreds of error messages:

Warning: ksort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /www/doc/domain/www/wp-content/themes/theme/plugins/bbpress/includes/core/template-functions.php on line 316

Warning: reset() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /www/doc/domain/www/wp-content/themes/theme/plugins/bbpress/includes/core/template-functions.php on line 321

.............

Does anybody know how to integrate it? it would be great if there is some tutorial. everywhere i find how to use it, or the 4 steps to install it by zip uploading.

thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

There are reasons that plugins are kept separate from themes and located in a different directory and there is a fair amount of debate as to what belongs in a plugin and what belongs in a theme.

The problem is that bb-press was written as a plugin and the paths expect it to be in the plugin directory. In order to include it directly into the theme you would have to rewrite all paths in the plugin. I don't think this is an advisable course of action but if you really want to do this you could a find and replace to change all the paths put given the complexity of bbPress you are likely to encounter problems nontheless.

Or you could have it automatically install with the theme like [As described in this article](http://thomasgriffinmedia.com/blog/2011/09/automatically-install-plugins-with-themes-for-wordpress/)

Another problem with including a plugin is that your wouldn't benefit from security updates and with something like bbPress where there is content written into your db by the general public, the risk would be very high.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for help. i allready tried this TGM class to include WPBakery Visual Composer, but its not possible to simply add it to my theme for user to not have to install it. The point is i have about 10 plugins in my theme and when user will install my theme, he will have 10 notices that he must install some plugins. its pretty annoing for users to have to install something. i think the logic would be better if he buy theme, install it, activate it and start to use it and not have to waste time on some installing additional plugins, you see me.

Comment: There may be other plugins that are better suited to be included in the theme and some offer instructions on doing so. You could try the BBPress forum and ask advice but I think they'll probably agree that its better left as a plugin.